# inequality on convex hull

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, optimization, convex-analysis

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two convex hulls and $Q\subseteq P$.If a linear inequality $ax\geq b$ is valid for $Q$,Is it valid for $P$?

Comment: $P=[0,3]$, $Q=[1,2]$, $x\ge 1$ is valid on $Q$ but not on $P$.

Comment: The reverse inclusion $P\subseteq Q$ is more interesting.